# Javascript Function Not Returning Value to CSHTML

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am having a strange problem.  My javascript function appears to be working fine, when I `alert("1"+res)` it gives me the desired results but I am trying to set a checkbox with the boolean it returns and it just will not work.  I must be missing something stupid, here is my code first the javascript function:

```
function GetDisplayImages() {

        if (localStorage.DisplayImages) {
            var name = "DisplayImages=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0, len = ca.length; i < len; i++) {
                var c = ca[i].trim();
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {

                    var res = c.substring(name.length, c.length);

                    // resetting, just in case local storage not in sync.
                    self.SetDisplayImages(res);

                    if (self.Debug) {
                        toastr.info(res, "Returning Display Images setting from Cookie", { timeOut: 0, extendedTimeOut: 0 });
                    }
                    alert("1"+res);
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

As mentioned the `alert("1"+res)` displays the desired value.  I can't seem to get that value from the .cshtml file I call the function from though.  Here is that code there:

```
chk.onload = function (e) {
    alert("2"+Library.settings.GetDisplayImages());
    this.value = Library.settings.GetDisplayImages();
}
```

The `alert(Library.settings.GetDisplayImages());` doesn't even popup but I know the function is being called, because the alert in the javascript function does show up.  Please help me so I can stop bashing my head against my desk! :)

There are actually 2 errors and here they are:
[image]
Here is my whole script section:

```
@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        chk = document.getElementById("chkDisplayImages");

        chk.onload = function (e) {
            alert(Library.settings.GetDisplayImages());
            this.value = Library.settings.GetDisplayImages();
        }

        chk.onchange = function (e) {
            Library.settings.SetDisplayImages(this.checked);
        }
    });
    </script>

 }
```

The `SetDisplayImages()` works perfectly for some reason.

Comment: check your console (F12 in the browser) and post which errors you receive, if any.

Comment: I thought I wasn't getting an error but it turns out for some reason it just disappears after less than a second.  It says "no element found"

Comment: can you pinpoint the line that issues the error? drop a `console.log("1/2/3/etc...")` here and there and see between which logs the error pops. or debug it and go line by line

Comment: Where are you calling this function on your page? Before the element exists on the page, or after?

Comment: wrap your code in `document.onload = function () { /*your code here */ }`

Comment: wrapping it in the document.onload didn't seem to help.  The no element error says line 1 but I don't think my ViewBag.Title = "View"; is causing issues.  I will add my entire javascript snippet.

Comment: it seems as though my onload function isn't firing when I place an alert("test") in there before trying to set the checkbox is doesn't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there were 2 problems, one my onload wasn't firing, two a string was being returned not a boolean.  This is what I had to do to get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    chk = document.getElementById("chkDisplayImages");

    chk.onchange = function (e) {
        Library.settings.SetDisplayImages(this.checked);
    }

    window.onload(setCheckbox());

    function setCheckbox()
    {
        if (Library.settings.GetDisplayImages()=="true") 
            chk.checked = true;
        else 
            chk.checked = false;
    }

</script>
```

Not the cleanest way to do this, but it seemed to be the only thing that would work and I need to move on.